# Django resync autoincrementing pk with restored database

Tags: django, postgresql

I am working on a feature that requires me to use `pg_restore` to restore a database so I have enough historical data to do what I need to locally. The problem with this is when I create a new instance of any model, I end up with an `IntegrityError` as the pk is not unique.

This has something to do with auto-incrementing behavior of pks when creating, but it doesn't seem like Django is using that last row to "resync" the next number so what I'm left with is Django trying to create a new instance with pk of 1361 despite there being 31k rows.

How can I set the next value to what the next value actually should be, and is there a reliable way to do this after every restore?

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for was `sqlsequencereset` in `manage.py` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#sqlsequencereset) which will generate the necessary SQL statements for me to run to resync.

```
sqlsequencereset app_label [app_label ...]
```

Running the following command gives the following output:

```
> python manage.py sqlsequencereset api
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
api.ArchivedStream.tags: (fields.W340) null has no effect on ManyToManyField.
api.ArchivedStream.viewer_counts: (fields.E010) ArrayField default should be a callable instead of an instance so that it's not shared between all field instances.
    HINT: Use a callable instead, e.g., use `list` instead of `[]`.
api.Stream.stream_data: (fields.W904) django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField is deprecated. Support for it (except in historical migrations) will be removed in Django 4.0.
    HINT: Use django.db.models.JSONField instead.
api.Stream.tags: (fields.W340) null has no effect on ManyToManyField.
api.Stream.viewer_counts: (fields.E010) ArrayField default should be a callable instead of an instance so that it's not shared between all field instances.
    HINT: Use a callable instead, e.g., use `list` instead of `[]`.
api.Video.tags: (fields.W340) null has no effect on ManyToManyField.
BEGIN;
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"tags"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "tags";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"streamers"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "streamers";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"streams_tags"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "streams_tags";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"streams"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "streams";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"videos_tags"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "videos_tags";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"videos"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "videos";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"archived_streams_tags"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "archived_streams_tags";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"archived_streams"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "archived_streams";
COMMIT;
```

Now I just needed to run this with `psql` command line. In my case, my postgres instance is in docker, so I ran the following command to execute the statements in my container.

````
sudo docker-compose run app python manage.py sqlsequencereset | sudo docker-compose run db psql -U postgres -d postgres```
````